# NoClassDefFoundError when attempting to run unit tests when building Jenkins plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a custom Jenkins plugin that I've built. I have some test cases that leverage some code out of the `jenkins-test-harness` project (namely the Junit JenkinsRule.)

Anyway, the unit tests run and pass when I run them in IntelliJ. No exceptions, no errors.

When I try to run them from the Maven commandline, however, all of the tests that rely on the `JenkinsRule` fail:

```
[ERROR] testGetLastDate(com.mycompany.myplugin.portlet.utils.UtilsHudsonTest)  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jvnet.hudson.test.TestPluginManager
        at org.jvnet.hudson.test.JenkinsRule.<init>(JenkinsRule.java:325)
        at com.mycompany.myplugin.portlet.utils.UtilsHudsonTest.<init>(UtilsHudsonTest.java:19)
```

That TestPluginManager is [in the jenkins-test-harness jar](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-test-harness/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hudson/test/TestPluginManager.java). The JenkinsRule that attempts to call it is right next to it in the same package in the same jar, so clearly the jar itself is successfully on the classpath.

I can't quite figure out why I can't run this job from the commandline using `mvn test`.

My POM is very simple -- I declare a Parent on the Jenkins plugin-3.2 pom:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
  <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

And I have a dependency on the test harness:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>dashboard-view</artifactId>
      <version>${dashboard-view.version}</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.main</groupId>
      <artifactId>jenkins-test-harness</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <version>2.34</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

(That's the entire dependencies section, no omissions.)

And in my build section, I only declare the compiler, surefire, and hpi plugins:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-hpi-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>hpi</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

(The surefire config is inherited from the plugin-3.2 parent.)

Here's the bit of the UtilHudsonTest that causes the error -- line 19 is the `@Rule` annotation:

```
public class UtilsHudsonTest {

    @Rule // This is line 19
    public JenkinsRule j = new JenkinsRule();

    @Test
    public void testGetLastDate() throws Exception {
        FreeStyleProject prj = j.createFreeStyleProject("prj1");
        prj.scheduleBuild2(0).get();
        FreeStyleProject prj2 = j.createFreeStyleProject("prj2");
        prj2.scheduleBuild2(0).get();

        List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();
        jobs.add(prj);
        jobs.add(prj2);

        LocalDate lastDate = Utils.getLastDate(jobs);
        assertNotNull(lastDate);
    }

    // other tests
}
```

I'm kind of stumped why this would work in IntelliJ and not in Maven. A `mvn dependency:tree` shows that the correct and expected dependencies. Any ideas in how to get this plugin to successfully run its test from commandline?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, I ended up doing a manual build with first a local test run and then a build/deploy from the CI with `-DskipTests`. If this wasn't a one-off plugin it wouldn't be a sufficient solution. But since Jenkins' documentation is extremely lacking and no answers were forthcoming here, I had few other choices.